# Merge 2 fields from same table?

Tags: mysql, join, internationalization, union

I'm working on a translations table. I want to merge the translations so that I have a fallback in another language.

```
tbl `cms`
+----+-------+--------+
| id | other | other1 |
+----+-------+--------+
|  1 | na    | na     |
|  2 | na    | na     |
+----+-------+--------+

tbl `translations`
+--------+--------+-------------+--------+
| cms_id | locale |     key     | value  |
+--------+--------+-------------+--------+
|      1 | en     | title       | Coffee |
|      1 | pl     | title       | Kawa   |
|      2 | en     | description | Black  |
|      2 | pl     | description |        |
+--------+--------+-------------+--------+
```

In this example, if the user was in Polish language, as there is currently no entry for the `description` field, I want to output the English "Black".

```
SELECT * 
FROM cms
LEFT JOIN translations t_en ON cms.id = t_en.cms_id AND locale = 'en'
LEFT JOIN translations t_pl ON cms.id = t_pl.cms_id AND locale = 'pl'
FROM translations
```

Now I want to merge the `translations.value` field from the joins, can I do this by union? Or is there a JOIN method I could use?

```
SELECT 
t_en.value
UNION
t_pl.value
FROM cms
LEFT JOIN translations t_en ON cms.id = t_en.cms_id AND locale = 'en'
LEFT JOIN translations t_pl ON cms.id = t_pl.cms_id AND locale = 'pl'
FROM translations
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the join approach.  You would want to use `COALESCE()` in the `SELECT`.  If you want priority to the Polist value, then put that first in the `COALESCE()`:

```
SELECT cms.id, COALESCE(t_pl.value, t_en.value)
FROM cms LEFT JOIN
     translations t_en
     ON cms.id = t_en.cms_id AND t_en.locale = 'en' LEFT JOIN
     translations t_pl
     ON cms.id = t_pl.cms_id AND t_pl.locale = 'pl';
```

I should note that `COALESCE()` returns the first non-NULL value from a list of arguments, so you can add additional languages, if you like.

Answer (score 0):

In your example you should use [CASE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html) statement

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN t_pl.value IS NOT NULL AND t_pl.value != '' THEN t_pl.value 
        ELSE t_en.value
    END AS value

FROM cms
LEFT JOIN translations t_en ON cms.id = t_en.cms_id AND locale = 'en'
LEFT JOIN translations t_pl ON cms.id = t_pl.cms_id AND locale = 'pl'
FROM translations
```